# How to collect physical system memory usage and virtual system memory usage for android

Tags: android, ios, memory, system

I don't how to collect physical system memory and virtual system memory usage for android, I mean the total usage of the system. Some command like "adb shell top" can collect the memory usage of individual process, but I can't just add together, it's meaningless. I want observe the memory usage berfore my app launched and after app exited. And also, what is the solution on IOS?